# Unable to load content in iframe, " X-frame options to deny."

Tags: visualforce, iframe

Ideally in our project, a third party application is hosting Visual force pages in a iframe. Is it failing on all the browsers, saying unable to load the content or X-FRAME OPTIONS TO DENY.

Can someone please guide me over this.

Comment: third party application is a dotnet application, and we are using SOAP api for login method into salesforce.